# Rendering and Re-Rendering components or conditional bases - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change components rendering on button click.

On button click **state** gets changed. And on state change i want to render a different component.

```
<button className="btn orange-btn" onClick={() => {this.setTableView(true)}}>Table View</button>
<button className="btn orange-btn" onClick={() => {this.setTableView(false)}}>Slips View</button>
```

Above buttons will change state to TRUE, or FALSE.

```
setTableView(tableview){
   thisclass.setState({tableview: tableview});
}
```

And render components on state change.

```
{this.state.tableview ?
          <Paymenttable/>
         :
          <div>
           <Payslip />
           <Payslip />
         </div>
}
```

But getting an error:

> Attempted to update component `Paymenttable` that has already been unmounted (or failed to mount).

And

> Cannot read property 'getHostNode' of null

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Check for async actions in `Paymentable`. Things like `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. Do you have any? Please post the code for `Paymentable`.

Comment: @Andrew No, nothing like that in `Paymenttable`. Just a table.

Comment: I've had a similar problem in the past. Can you please show us the code for `Paymenttable` anyways?